# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to connect to an API but i'm getting the error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://valgresultat.no/api/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My proxy.config.json

```
{
    "/api/": {
       "target":  {
         "host": "valgresultat.no",
         "protocol": "http:",
         "port": 80
       },
       "secure": false,
       "changeOrigin": true,
       "logLevel": "info"
     }
   }
```

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  private apiUrl = '/api/';
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello fellow user');
    this.getContacts();
    this.getData();
  }
  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getContacts() {
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not angular related, this is more of a server configuration. You need to enable CORS on your server that provide your API.

Comment: exactly, this is a CORS issue, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. You should enable method OPTIONS response with properly configured request/response headers.

Answer (score 0):

**Install CORS chrome extension** then you can connect to your api
Please find the link to install CORS plugin below
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors/dboaklophljenpcjkbbibpkbpbobnbld?hl=en